# Is it faster to initialize a value with a bitwise operation or a numeric literal?

Tags: java, hashmap, bitwise-operators, bit-shift

I was going through source code of `HashMap` . I saw something like
  `static final int DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY = 1 << 4; // aka 16.` I want to know why they are using shift operator. Does this speed up calculation or something. So I looked for `byte` differences between these three operations:

```
int DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY =  0x10;
L0
    LINENUMBER 52 L0
    BIPUSH 16
    ISTORE 1



int DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY1 =  1 << 4;
  L1
    LINENUMBER 54 L1
    BIPUSH 16
    ISTORE 2

int test = 16;
 L2
    LINENUMBER 56 L2
    BIPUSH 16
    ISTORE 3
```

Does it matter how the value is initialized?

Comment: Looks like you've answered your own question.

Comment: Yes, bit wise operations are faster

Comment: Regardless of if bit wise operations are faster or not, compilers in most languages will resolve operations involving constants at compile time.  So statements like that will never matter in terms of execution time.

Comment: It doesn't matter in this case due to compiler optimizations.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Believe it or not, it's actually about readability. The expression `1 << 4` surely doesn't evaluate faster than the expression `16`. Plus, whatever the expression is, it is evaluated at compile time.

The point of using the shift-representation is that it is a more natural way to express round binary numbers. The invariant for initial capacity, as well as for many other things in hashtable implementations, is that it must be a pure power of two. This is communicated more directly with the expression `1 << n` (equivalent to 2<sup>n</sup>) than the decimal representation, especially when you go into higher values of `n` (such as anything higher than 16, for example).

Answer (score 5):

As you figured out by yourself, byte code is identical for constant 16 or 1 << 4. In this particular case I suppose it is just a matter of readability: to emphasise that initial capacity should be a power of 2 (by shifting 1 to the left you can get only powers of 2). This is what I have in sources for HashMap:

```
/**
 * The default initial capacity - MUST be a power of two.
 */
static final int DEFAULT_INITIAL_CAPACITY = 1 << 4; // aka 16
```

Answer (score 4):

from a speed perspective, it is probably not an advantage. However, it looks like a HashMap's `capacity` is always a power of 2 (even specifying the capacity in the constructor results in a call to `Collections.roundUpToPowerOfTwo(capacity)`), so notating it in the form `1 << x` ensures this restriction trivially, even if you were to change `x`. the other forms would be easier to mess up when changing if you weren't aware of the restriction

Answer (score 3):

Below is a timed test of the three initialization methods described in your question.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int test = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
        test = 16;
    }
    
    System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + " : " + test);
    
    time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int test2 = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
        test2 = 1 << 4;
    }
    
    System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + " : " + test2);
    
    time = System.currentTimeMillis();
    int test3 = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100000; i++){
        test3 = 0x10;
    }
    
    System.out.println((System.currentTimeMillis() - time) + " : " + test3);
}
```

running this yields

> 2 : 16
>
> 2 : 16
>
> 2 : 16

each time it's + or - 5ms for each execution. This indicates it's pretty much irrelevant how the value is initialized.

**conclusion:**

It makes no **programmatic** difference which method is used to initialize the value.

It seems that the only reason to use `1 << 4` over `16` or `0x10` is to enforce that the initial value is a power of 2.

Comment: Your conclusion is correct, but your benchmark is only conicidentially supporting it. Microbenchmarks are a touchy subject; there are many factors that can screw up the relative results. Furthermore, 1 << 4 is a compile time constant, so regardless if you write test = 16 | 0x10 | 1 << 4, the same bytecodes are created by the compiler (check out the generated code with the javap utility).

Comment: To be clear, I'm not claiming that execution will always take exactly 2ms for each operation. To account for the inherit benchmark variability at the scale of single milliseconds, I put the + / - 5ms. I've run the test several times and never gotten more than 7ms and frequently gotten 0ms. a few times it turned out that they were all 2ms, I'm using the rough average to say they are more or less the same. Considering that they are compile-time constants, would that not enforce the validity of this?

Comment: There are many pitfalls with benchmarking; to the point where you can't even take the simplest assumptions for granted (e.g. identical loops perform differently depending on containing scope). There is this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12035676 (and answers) that demonstrate the case. I said "conincidentially" because you were lucky enogh that your three loops in one method didn't suffer from that effect.

Answer (score 2):

basically shift operators are used to work on bits and are more fast than working on other operators like +,-

example-
to multiply two number what CPU will do is it will internally perform multiply by replacing it with addition and subtraction and it is nothing but shifting and performing AND,OR,NOT etc. operation on bits.

so if you are working directly on bits it means you are doing the work which has to be done by CPU after lots of processing.

also see:
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op3.html

Comment: You are right that `bitwise` operations are much faster than standard `arithmetic` operations. But the OP isn't asking about `arithmetic` vs `bitwise` operations. He seems to be instead asking about the difference between `bitwise` operations and numeric literal values.

Comment: I've also given a link for more explanation also. @LanguidSquid

Comment: Yeah, it's good to provide links to resources, but the meat of your answer is with regard to the differences between `bitwise` and `arithmetic` operations. Maybe you should rephrase the content of the answer to better address the question being asked?